# Lubridate get date of certain day in a month

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to aggregate my dates on the monthly level. I would like to use the last Saturday of a certain month as the date for that month. 
I can get the date of a Saturday in a week by doing:

```
as.Date(paste(6, week(mdy(mydate)), year(mdy(mydate)), sep="-"), "%u-%W-%Y")
```

but months have different numbers of days, so I cant just do:

```
as.Date(paste(6, month(mdy(mydate)), year(mdy(mydate)), sep="-"), "%U-%m-%Y")
```

This doesn't even work, even if I was just trying to get the date of the 6th day of a month.

How can I get the date of the last Saturday of a month? So given a date `09-15-2014` I would get `09-27-2014`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) zoo/cut** In the [zoo Quick Reference vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf) this function appears which given a `"Date"` class variable, `x`, returns the same date if its Friday or the next Friday if not:

```
library(zoo)
nextfri <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x-5+4) / 7) + as.Date(5-4)
```

Replacing the 5 with 6 will give the next Saturday

```
nextsat <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x-6+4) / 7) + as.Date(6-4)
```

Now if `x` is the input and is of Date class, get the first of its month using `cut`, then get the first of the next month using `cut` again, find the next Saturday using `nextsat` and then subtract 7 to get the last Saturday of the input date's month.

```
the.first <- as.Date(cut(x, "month"))
next.month <- as.Date(cut(the.first + 32, "month")
nextsat(next.month) - 7
```

To test is out:

```
library(zoo)
x <- as.Date("2014-09-15")
nextsat <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x-6+4) / 7) + as.Date(6-4)
the.first <- as.Date(cut(x, "month"))
next.month <- as.Date(cut(the.first + 32, "month"))
nextsat(next.month) - 7
## [1] "2014-09-27"
```

This only uses vectorized functions so if `x` were a vector of dates it would still work.

**1a) zoo/as.yearmon.Date/as.Date.yearmon** We can shorten this by using the fact that `as.Date(as.yearmon(x), frac = 1)` is the date of the last day of the month where `as.yearmon.Date` and `as.Date.yearmon` are zoo methods:

```
library(zoo)
x <- as.Date("2014-09-15")
nextsat <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x-6+4) / 7) + as.Date(6-4)
nextsat(as.Date(as.yearmon(x), frac = 1) + 1) - 7
## [1] "2014-09-27"
```

This is also vectorized.

**2) zoo/lubridate** The above did not use lubridate but we can rework (1) to use lubridate like this:

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
nextsat <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x-6+4) / 7) + as.Date(6-4)
x <- as.Date("2014-09-15")
xx <- x
day(xx) <- 1
month(xx) <- month(xx) + 1
nextsat(xx) - 7
## [1] "2014-09-27"
```

This is also vectorized.

Answer (score 4):

Using standard R date functions:

```
x <- as.Date(c("09-15-2014","09-15-2014"),format="%m-%d-%Y")

lastsat <- function(x,day) {
 bits <- sapply(x, function(i) {
  res <- seq.Date(as.Date(format(i,"%Y-%m-01")),length=2,by="1 month")[2] - (1:7)
  res[format(res, "%u") == as.character(day)]
 })
 as.Date(bits, origin="1970-01-01")
}

lastsat(x,6)
#[1] "2014-09-27" "2014-09-27"
```