# Number of days that have occurred so far in the month in R

Tags: r

I trying to get the number of days that have happened so far in the month. So as of today, 8 days in June have occurred. So I would return 8.

I would also like to return number of days up to last Saturday. So it would return 4 since last Saturday was June 4

Comment: `d <- Sys.Date(); as.numeric(format(d, "%d"))` and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226453/lubridate-get-date-of-certain-day-in-a-month

Comment: This is exactly what the function `lubridate::mday` does for any given date

Comment: @AllanCameron Youre the best. Thank you. If youd like to be marked as the answer you could post one